# Should equal signs be escaped in Regex in general?

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, escaping, pcre

I started learning some Perl Compatible regex and yet I've seen various codes in the last years (Bash, APCRE, Nginx, JavaScript, ) and in some I clearly remember seeing a escaping metacharacter right before equal signs while in some others I haven't seen that.

Is it generally a necessity in regex or some kind of a best practice?

Comment: Do not escape `=`, it is not a special regex metacharacter. The best practice is to avoid escaping chars that are not special.

Comment: in vim, patterns starting with `\v` is *very magic* when `=` means `{0,1}`. you can say that's vim style regex (just like PCRE). voted to reopen.

Comment: according to vim's manual, *Use of `\v` means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `_` have a special meaning.  "very magic"*